# class members vs. static members in Vala

Tags: vala

I have seen https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Manual/Classes#Types_of_class_members and tested several times. As a result, I assume this

static members : can be accessed in a class & sub-classes of it & all instances of these
class members : can be accessed in *all instances* of (a class & sub-classes of it)

Is this right? And are there any other differences?

Comment: Not sure about Vala. In somewhat every other language it's that static method's are like functions (they do not have any state) and non-static methods work on instances of the class.

Comment: With variables: static is like a class variable (all instances share it + it can be accessed without an instance).

Comment: I know about the languages such as java, c# too. the concept in vala is static members. AFAIK class members works like instance members (e.g. can't do `Foo.class_func();` that makes 'Access to instance member' error) except class members will execute in scope of the class, can't be `virtual`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's check using the `--ccode` switch of the Vala compiler:

```
public class Test {
    public static int static_member;
    public class int class_member;
    public int instance_member;
}
```

When compiled will produce these C data structures (I only show the important parts):

```
struct _Test {
        gint instance_member;
};

struct _TestClass {
        gint class_member;
};

extern gint test_static_member;
```

The static member is not stored in any structure belonging to the class, but is a global variable. It is still scoped using the class prefix (so "test_" is prepended) to avoid name clashes with other global variables or static members of other classes.

The class member is stored in the "class structure" and the instance member is stored in the "instance structure".

The "class structure" may be extended by deriving classes, but other than that you normally only have one instance of the "class structure" for each class (which is why they are named like this).

The "instance structure" holds all the instance data everytime a new instance is created.

For the full understanding of these mechanism you have to know some C and have to read the GObject manual.